# Fatal error Out of memory with simple_dom_html

Tags: php, curl, out-of-memory, simple-html-dom

I'm having problems with the above error. I'm sure i have tried some ways in the previous topics, and not solved.

I'm solving an algorithm related to curl and simple_dom_html. I use a lot of recursive function and foreach to repeat the initialization simple_dom_html. Imagine all the above steps to run within a day or more. But when you run it suddenly stopped and did not show any error messages. I tried to examination php_errors_log and found that:

> - PHP Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1,843,920,896) (tried to allocate 24 bytes) in simple_html_dom.php on line (1148, 1451, 1396, ... )

I don't doubt my code has problem because I tried to run with limited, it success. Example : I have about 10000 page, it's running about 5% it ! Then, it don't run again. I've tried a lot of ways:

```
 - $domHtml->clear(), unset($domHtml), $domHtml = ''
```

- Config in code :

> ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
>       ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);
>       ini_set('max_input_time', -1);

- Or Config in php.ini like above
- I try vagrant with scotch box, not work too.

Here is my sample code :

```
/**
     * Create new Curl
     * @return 
     */
    private function initCurl($url = null) 
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        $this->autoSetOpt($ch, $url);
        return $ch;
    }


    /**
     * Auto set Option. This is demo
     * @return
     */
    private function autoSetOpt($ch, $url = null) 
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, trim($url));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip,deflate");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT  , 20);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
    }


    /**
     * Execute curl function
     * @return 
     */
    private function exec_curl($ch) 
    {
        return curl_exec($ch);
    }

    /**
     * Close Curl
     * @return
     */
    public function close($ch) 
    {
        curl_close($ch);
    }



public function scanTrackInList($arrTracks = array(), $arrLink = array(), $type = 'song')
    {

        if (empty($arrLink[0])) {
            $link = $arrLink[1];
        } else {
            $link = $arrLink[0];
        }
        $ch = $this->initCurl($link);
        $domHtml = str_get_html($this->exec_curl($ch));
        $this->close($ch);
        unset($ch);

        if ($domHtml) {
            if (count($domHtml->find('html',0)) > 0) {
                if ($type == 'song') {
                    $index = '.list-item h3.txt-primary a';
                } else {
                    $index = '.album-item h3.title-item a';
                }
                foreach($domHtml->find($index) as $element) {
                    if ($this->detectZingMp3Url($element->href)) {
                        $arrOb = $this->getObjectTrack($element->href);
                        if ($arrOb) {
                            $arrDetail = array();
                            if ($arrOb[0]->type == 'mp3') {

                                $arrDetail = $this->getDetailSong($element->href);
                            } elseif ($arrOb[0]->type == 'video') {
                                $arrDetail = $this->getDetailSong($element->href);
                            }
                            if (!$arrOb || !$arrDetail) {
                                return $this->scanTrackInList($link, $arrLink, $count);
                            }
                            $arrTracks[] = array_merge($arrOb, $arrDetail);
                        }
                    }
                }


                $domHtml->clear();
                unset($domHtml);


                array_splice($arrLink,0,1);

            } else {
                $domHtml->clear();
                unset($domHtml);



                return $this->scanTrackInList($arrTracks, $arrLink, $type, $count);
            }
        } else {


            return $this->scanTrackInList($link, $arrLink, $count);
        }   

        if (count($arrLink) > 0) {         

            return $this->scanTrackInList($arrTracks,$arrLink, $type, $count + 1);
        }

        return $arrTracks;
    }
```

With :

- $arrTracks : my result
- $arrLink : The url collection will run.
- $type : Don't care it. Just type song or video.

This is only a small step. I have 2-3 times. And runtime unpredictable. It may take several days.

Please help me ! Tell me if you have any solution for them. Thanks for all !